# Can't find out how to create a program that uses pointer, char and for function combined

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in learning c++ and i was doing an exercise where i use an array with the variable char on the function for, to create a loop where each time it repeats itself it should show an letter of the name typed in char, here is the code that i could create:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
//The purpose of this program is to ask for the user to type his name, and then his name will be repeated by the program by using a loop in the command for, where each of the letters of his/her name will be shown separately.
{
    int i; //Declares the variable int with the name "i"
    char name[55]; //Declares the variable char with the name "name"
    cin.get(name, 55); //Asks for the user input his own name.
    char* pointname=name; // Transforms the variable char name in to the pointer with the name "*point name"
    for(i=0;i<56;i++) // Creates a loop where it will show the name that the user has insert and ignore the rest of it if it has more than 55 letters.
    {
        cout << "Char array= [" << i << "]=" << *pontname << endl; // Each time the loop repeats here, it should show an letter of the name of the user, followed in the next loop by the next letter. But it is only showing the first letter of the name of the user.
    }
    return 0; // Closes the program.
}
```

Sorry for any mispelling or mistake.

Comment: Quick note: comments are better reserved for 'why' and not 'what'. Programmers can tell what is happening by just seeing the code. For example, it's obvious that you declared an int and named it i. It's right there. That comment does nothing for anyone. Explaining why you think you need 'i' would be better (hint: you don't). Also, what exactly is your question?

Comment: There's a LOT wrong this code, but if all you want is a review, you should post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The problem you're having is also quite simple. You don't need 'pointname', just use name[i].

Comment: Code Review should be reserved for code that works but you suspect can be made better, be it work better, be simpler, or simply look better. This isn't ready for code review yet.

Comment: Unrelated: `std::iostream::get` has a lot of caveats. I strongly recommend you [read some good documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to get the straight dope on how it works.

Comment: @sweenish, Ty I didn't knew that here was the wrong place to ask that question.
Also about point name, in that exercise i'm forbidden to declare directly the array name, i have to use it's pointer, so i named it pointname(pointer name).

Comment: @user4581301,Ty I will certainly read all that content and will try to come out with a solution.

Comment: @Stark the cppreference documentation I linked can read like it's written in Martian. If you have trouble with it, see if the [cplusplus.com version](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) is easier to read, then return to the more precise documentation for finer-grained details if you need them.

Comment: Never say for function, you must say for loop.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my post, the solution posted by Mauricio R solved my problem, I feel silly now that i took so long for thinking in using pointname++ xD

Comment: @MauricioR I know, but i didn't found any better term to name it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you need to increment `pointname`  var to move your pointer to each letter in the char array. For example you can write your for loop in this way:

`for(i=0;i<56 && *pointname!= '\0' ;i++,pointname++)`

With this you assure to finish the cycle when find the null character.

Comment: Thank you, i just got to that result right now and saw your answer.
My code still, was sending random characters for the rest of the non-used spaces in char, but looks like the function of != that you introduced solved it.
I also didn't know that the function not equal(!=) could be used that way, I'm really grateful.

Comment: `i<56` is a copy of a mistake made by OP. This will be one past the end of the array. Probably not necessary as `get` always stops one character before the given count to fit in a null terminator.

Comment: @user4581301 Yea, that's what i thought because if the person's name have 55 characters, it would only show up the 54 first ones if i used i<55.
I still don't know if it would cause a big trouble in the program if use it like this...

Comment: @Stark `for(i=0; *pointname!= '\0' ;i++,pointname++)` should be enough, though you should also test to make sure `get` got anything in the first place. If it didn't all bets are off as to what's in `name`. Something like `if (cin.get(name, 55)) { code that uses name (or pointers to it) }`

Comment: @user4581301 Got it, ty.
Now i  already moved on to another exercises, hope guys like y'all are there to answer me if i have any questions! :)